# LSTM to forecast numerical data by having categorical data as input

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, forecast

I have a similar `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
{'date':'2021-01-15', 'value':145, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-16', 'value':144, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-17', 'value':147, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-18', 'value':146, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-19', 'value':155, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-20', 'value':157, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-21', 'value':158, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-22', 'value':157, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-23', 'value':157, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-24', 'value':152, 'label':'positive'}, 
{'date':'2021-01-25', 'value':159, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-26', 'value':162, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-27', 'value':160, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-28', 'value':153, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-29', 'value':149, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-01-30', 'value':156, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-01-31', 'value':168, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-02-01', 'value':179, 'label':'negative'},
{'date':'2021-02-02', 'value':184, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-02-03', 'value':189, 'label':'positive'},
{'date':'2021-02-04', 'value':196, 'label':'positive'}])
```

I have already converted `date` column strings into `datetime` format and set it as index with `set_index` method.

Once `n` and `m` are fixed, I would like to use a Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM) to predict last `n` values of the `value` column by taking into account the categories of the `label` column only.

I have just encoded `label` column features with the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False).fit_transform(df.label.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
```

and scaled data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df.value.values)
```

but I cannot succeed in taking into account `m` and `n` conditions to build train and test set.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to transform the dataset into a time-series form that supported by LSTM. build a model to predict the next day only and roll the testing process as the number of predictions you want from a single prediction. 
you can get complete from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras)

Comment: thanks nipun, I'll try to do that by learning from link you posted